# Spider Run from Script will not Crawl pages from start_urls seed

Tags: selenium-webdriver, scrapy, google-colaboratory

I have an issue crawling websites when I try to run the spider from a Google Colab script:

code for class:

```
    class Campaign_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
        #name of the spider
        name = "crowdfunder"
    
        # First Start Url
        start_urls= ["https://www.crowdfunder.co.uk/search/projects?category=Business&map=off"]
        
        npages = 83 # For full list of listed campaignswe could set this to 83
    
        # This mimics getting the pages using the next button. 
        for i in range(2, npages + 2 ):
            start_urls.append("https://www.crowdfunder.co.uk/search/projects?page="+str(i)+"&category=Business&map=off") 
    
        def parse(self, response):
            #print('This is the response' + response.url)
    
            for href in response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'cf-pod__link')]//@href"):
                url = href.extract()
    
                yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)
      
        def parse_page(self, response):
            pass
            #href = response.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'cf-pod__link')]//@href")
            # Extract the information
            # ...
            #yield {
                #'url': response.request.meta['referer'],
                # ...
            #}
```

Code for wrapper to crawl:

```
    # the wrapper to make it run more times
    def run_spider(spider):
        def f(q):
            try:
                runner = CrawlerProcess(settings={'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
            'FEEDS': {'crowdfunder.csv': {'format': 'csv', 'overwrite': True}}})
                
                deferred = runner.crawl(spider)
                deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
                reactor.run()
                q.put(None)
            except Exception as e:
                q.put(e)
    
        q = Queue()
        p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
        p.start()
        result = q.get()
        p.join()
    
        if result is not None:
            raise result
```

I have tried printing the response in the code and would like for each of the urls in the start_urls list to refer the spider to further webpages to explore. I would appreciate any advice as I would like to implement this spider from a Google Colab script.

The output from the config_log:

```
config_log() Heading -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PjEc.png
Response/no crawling -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/yW5vN.png
Spider stats output log -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/MATrA.png
```

Comment: Whats the issue?

Comment: From the log the spider only crawls the start_urls and is unable to explore the webpages in the extracted URL links, so I would be expecting 1000 (83*12 + 1*4) requests, each start-url should refer the spider to 12 further webpages with the exception of the final page which only has 4 featured webpages. I would appreciate any guidance/advice as to how to unpack the issue.

Comment: @Eleni the urls are generated with JavaScript. Open the network tab and search for `JSON` file type, you'll see there an `Alogolia` post request. Recreate this request to get the urls. Good luck.

Comment: @SuperUser thank you so much for your prompt response and for implementing this API, I would be keen to look into your suggested answer but with my very limited programming background I would like to further ask if it would be possible to extract data directly from the parsed JSON file in the response output, as I would not be launching the API request myself, so to feed this API url in the spider as a request.

Comment: @Eleni I added a solution. If it helps you please accept it, if not then update me whats wrong and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps I followed to get to the solution.

1. Open the website in a browser with [JavaScript turned off](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/javascript-settings-for-interactive-web-pages).

   Search for the urls and see that they didn't load.

   (Turned JavaScript on again).
2. I opened the [Developer Tools](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/index.html) in my browser, clicked the network tab and opened the webpage.
3. I searched for a `JSON` file, and I copied the request's headers, body, and url.

[image: Developer Tools]

4. Now we just need to recreate the request.

   Notice that I left the `Content-Length` from the headers, and that the request for the API is a `POST` request.

   Scrapy needs the payload to be a string so we use `json.dumps()` function on the payload.

   The response that we get is also a JSON so in order to parse it I use `response.json()`.

```py
import scrapy
import json


class Campaign_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "crowdfunder"
    npages = 83     # For full list of listed campaignswe could set this to 83

    # https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#avoiding-getting-banned
    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.6
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        api_url = 'https://7izdzrqwm2-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia for JavaScript (3.35.1); Browser (lite)&x-algolia-application-id=7IZDZRQWM2&x-algolia-api-key=9767ce6d672cff99e513892e0b798ae2'
        # headers for the API request
        headers = {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
            "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "DNT": "1",
            "Host": "7izdzrqwm2-dsn.algolia.net",
            "Origin": "https://www.crowdfunder.co.uk",
            "Pragma": "no-cache",
            "Referer": "https://www.crowdfunder.co.uk/",
            "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
            "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
            "Sec-Fetch-Site": "cross-site",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36"
        }

        for i in range(1, self.npages + 2):
            payload = {
                "requests": [{
                    "indexName": "frontendsearch",
                    "params": f"facetFilters=%5B%22category%3ABusiness%22%5D&hitsPerPage=12&page={str(i)}&aroundPrecision=1000&distinct=true&query=&insideBoundingBox=&facets=%5B%5D&tagFilters="
                }]
            }
            yield scrapy.Request(url=api_url, body=json.dumps(payload), method='POST', headers=headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        json_data = response.json()
        base_url = 'https://www.crowdfunder.co.uk'

        for hit in json_data.get('results')[0].get('hits'):
            url = f"{base_url}{hit.get('uri')}"
            # don't forget to add whatever headers you need
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        # parse whatever you want here from each webpage
        pass
```