# scraping a webpage by using the algolia api

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the following webpage:

"https://www.peterpanbmw.com/used-vehicles/"

Instead of writing a UI scraper using scrapy, because the data on the page loads via javascript, I was trying to just use the underlying api on the page.

when inspecting the network tab in chrome, it looks as though the data for the underlying search query is being handled by algolia  with the following parameters:

url was https://sewjn80htn-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(4.9.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.4.4)&x-algolia-api-key=179608f32563367799314290254e3e44&x-algolia-application-id=SEWJN80HTN

```
headers = {

'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
'Connection': "keep-alive",
'Content-Length': 1702,
'Host': "sewjn80htn-dsn.algolia.net",
'Origin': "https://www.peterpanbmw.com",
'Referer': "https://www.peterpanbmw.com/",
'Sec-Fetch-Dest': "empty",
'Sec-Fetch-Mode': "cors",
'Sec-Fetch-Site': "cross-site",
'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
'sec-ch-ua': ' "Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114" ',
'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
'sec-ch-ua-platform': "macOS",
}
```

Therefore, I tried the following approach in python:

```
import requests 

url = "https://sewjn80htn-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia%20for%20JavaScript%20(4.9.1)%3B%20Browser%20(lite)%3B%20JS%20Helper%20(3.4.4)&x-algolia-api-key=179608f32563367799314290254e3e44&x-algolia-application-id=SEWJN80HTN"

heads = {
    'Accept-Encoding': "gzip, deflate, br",
    'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    'Connection': "keep-alive",
    'Content-Length': "1702",
    'Host': "sewjn80htn-dsn.algolia.net",
    'Origin': "https://www.peterpanbmw.com",
    'Referer': "https://www.peterpanbmw.com/",
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': "empty",
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': "cors",
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': "cross-site",
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Google Chrome";v="114"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': "macOS",
}

response = requests.get(url, headers=heads)
```

This kept erroring out on me though.

Is it possible to call algolia APIs like this?... Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Well it looks like the api uses POST requests and you are using a GET request.  You also aren't including the payload with the request.  But Even if you did it looks like the url has an api-key and application ID as query parameters which usually means that the server will only accept requests from specific ip addresses.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75965801/16429780).